# Query pra remover duplicatas entrando em aparente loop infinito

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo diversos campos na minha tabela porém tenho 4 que estão sendo repetidos e não posso permitir registro com esses campos iguais: `COD`, `TIPO_ATIVIDADE`, `DT_VENCIMENTO`, `EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM.

já tentei 4 códigos diferentes, inclusive com auxílio das perguntas antigas aqui do fórum e mesmo assim, sempre que executo a query, ela fica executando eternamente, não dá erro nem dá sucesso, somente fica executando e não sai nunca do "loop".

Códigos que tentei:

```sql
DELETE b FROM tbl_atividades a
INNER JOIN tbl_atividades b ON a.cod = b.cod AND a.tipo_atividade=b.tipo_atividade AND a.dt_vencimento=b.dt_vencimento AND b.codigo < a.codigo
```

```sql
DELETE t1 FROM tbl_atividades t1, tbl_atividades t2 WHERE t1.codigo > t2.codigo AND t1.cod = t2.cod AND t1.tipo_atividade = t2.tipo_atividade AND t1.dt_vencimento = t2.dt_vencimento AND t1.extra_urgente_comum = 'C'
```

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl_atividades
USING tbl_atividades, tbl_atividades AS auxtable
WHERE (NOT tbl_atividades.codigo = auxtable.codigo)
AND (tbl_atividades.cod = auxtable.cod)
AND (tbl_atividades.tipo_atividade = auxtable.tipo_atividade)
AND (tbl_atividades.dt_vencimento = auxtable.dt_vencimento)
AND (tbl_atividades.extra_urgente_comum = 'C')
```

Como eu poderia realizar essa exclusão de duplicadas outra forma?

Comment: É muito grande essa tabela? Tem índices?

Comment: Tem sim, é grande, mas a quantidade de duplicatas não é tanto. Possui 135606 registros, sendo que duplicados consta por volta 500 apenas.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro precisa saber que linhas estão duplicadas. Depois anular todas menos uma. Assim:

```
DELETE A 
FROM tbl_atividades A INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(codigo) AS codigo, cod, tipo_atividade, dt_vencimento, COUNT(*) as N
  FROM tbl_atividades
  WHERE extra_urgente_comum = 'C'
  GROUP BY cod, tipo_atividade, dt_vencimento
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS ToDELETE ON 
A.cod = ToDELETE.cod AND 
A.tipo_atividade = ToDELETE.tipo_atividade AND 
A.dt_vencimento = ToDELETE.dt_vencimento AND 
A.extra_urgente_comum = 'C' AND
A.codigo <> ToDELETE.codigo;
```

**Nota:** Antes de executar o delete execute primeiro este select, para validar quais os registos que vão ser removidos.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM tbl_atividades A INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(codigo) AS codigo, cod, tipo_atividade, dt_vencimento, COUNT(*) as N
  FROM tbl_atividades
  WHERE extra_urgente_comum = 'C'
  GROUP BY cod, tipo_atividade, dt_vencimento
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS ToDELETE ON 
A.cod = ToDELETE.cod AND 
A.tipo_atividade = ToDELETE.tipo_atividade AND 
A.dt_vencimento = ToDELETE.dt_vencimento AND 
A.extra_urgente_comum = 'C' AND
A.codigo <> ToDELETE.codigo
```